# How to specify a custom name of build files project in VueJs

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have a small problem with cache in production files
Mb someone know how i can specify custom name for js and css file in dist as like chunk-24545415.js?v=232315 
Or b someone know some guide about this

Comment: What build tool are you using? Webpack?

Comment: Have you looked here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55717783/any-webpack-splitchunks-name-as-a-function-documentation-other-than-from-the-web

Comment: Yes im using Webpack

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [Code Splitting](https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting/#dynamic-imports) and [Magic Comments](https://webpack.js.org/api/module-methods/#magic-comments) documentation.

In your `webpack.config.js` you can specify a format for the chunk filename.

```
module.exports = {
  //...
  output: {
    //...
    chunkFilename: '[id].js'
  }
};
```

Sadly, if you want a custom name for each chunk, the best solution I've found for Webpack is to use the Magic Comments.

Basically when you do an import, you put a special comment, specifying the name of the chunk.

```
 import(/* webpackChunkName: 'my-first-chunk' */ "./my-first-chunk.vue")
```

You also need to use `[name]` in the chunkFilename if you want to use magic comments.

`chunkFilename: '[name].js'`